# Is there a list of Greyhound partner bus carriers?

Tags: usa, buses, greyhound, vermont

Mostly in the US, but maybe also in Canada, Greyhound (the large bus network) partners with local carriers. However, the information about the partner carrier is limited when searching a schedule on Greyhound website (only a 3-letter identifier was given). Recently, I have searched the full itinerary of bus lines for a carrier indicated as `CLI` or another as `PRC`.

I used a search engine to figure the first was [Concord Coach Lines](http://concordcoachlines.com/) and find their network and schedules. However, I cannot figure this information for the carrier `PRC`, which seems to run a daily service between Hanover, NH and White River Jct, VT. Is there a catalog of the partnering bus carriers or does someone know specifically what carrier `PRC` is, and what is their network and schedule?

Comment: You also should save your dollar and [take the local bus](http://www.advancetransit.com/), which is free. The Orange Route runs hourly between Hanover and White River Junction all day.

Comment: @MichaelHampton That's true, that's what I did when I got there. I even found the website in the first place but I did not notice there were so many buses running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no (public) complete list of Greyhound's partner bus lines, as far as I know.

But PRC appears to be [Vermont Transit](https://www.vttranslines.com/) (aka Premier Coach). The one daily schedule you mentioned leaves Hanover, NH at 2:50 pm, arriving in White River Junction at 3:05 pm.

[image: Greyhound Hanover - White River Junction Schedule]

This corresponds exactly to [Vermont Transit's schedule](https://www.vttranslines.com/content/schedules/schedules.asp).

[image: Vermont Transit Hanover - White River Junction Schedule]

Concord Coach Lines and Vermont Transit are well known around here, as they provide services to New Hampshire and Vermont towns that Greyhound skips over (as they like to focus on larger cities).

---

Since this was written, Greyhound has redesigned their website, and now tells you the name of the partner bus companies when you select an itinerary.

[image: Hanover-White River Jct itinerary]